# How to make donator only commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am here today to ask you guys how I can make commands only for donators. I had this so far but it didn't seem to work...

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(819247032777834496)
async def cool(ctx):
  await ctx.send('B)')
```

Once you donated, it would've given you a role that gave you access to the commands! But, this doesn't seem to work for other servers. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the id of the role, this will be different on each server regardless of the name of the role. You can use the name of the role instead as `commands.has_any_role` supports that by default. For example:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Donor Role")
async def cool(ctx):
  await ctx.send('B)')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but that's not quite what I'm going for. I was thinking about when you donate you get special commands is there a way of doing that instead?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are looking to do. Are you asking how do you give a role to donators?

Comment: I'm basically trying to make donator-only commands. How can I do that?

Comment: How are you tracking who has donated? How are you tracking when someone makes as donation? Have you setup OAuth to link their discord account? The question you are asking is way to vague.

Comment: So when you donate, you get some commands. Like when you donate to Patreon, you get access through several commands only for donators